# Millisecond formatting in .Net DateTime

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, datetime-format

I'm formatting a DateTime for use in XML, and am using the ISO 8601 formatter "o". I've noticed this gives results such as the following:

```
2015-10-21T05:06:25.3800000-05:00
```

Similar output from other software seems to only include 3 places for the milliseconds portion, such as this:

```
2015-10-21T05:06:25.380-05:00
```

Aside from taking up a bit more room in the file, is there any issue with having the extra zeros in there? Is there some option to format with the shorter version in .Net without doing a custom formatter? I prefer to use the "o" format option just so it's a no brainer whether it's compatible or not.

Comment: Considering millisecond is 3 digits, why do you need more?

Comment: @ChuckSavage, I'm pretty sure the OP would prefer only three, but is considering whether that is worth swapping the simple `"o"` format specifier out for a format from scratch.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times), "There is no limit on the number of decimal places for the decimal fraction." So the question is whether the software you're communicating with can understand the format. If not, you have to write a custom format string (.NET's "o" is equal to `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffK" `)

Answer (score 0):

If you are serious about accurate date / time, consider using [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/).

If you're worried about space, then think of your own formatter, but the simplicity of the current method (which does the same as the "o"). What is worth your time, ease of programming (consider the following) or disk space?

```
XElement xdate = new XElement("date", DateTime.Now);
DateTime dnow = (DateTime)xdate;
```

The output, you'll notice looks like the "o", but different (mine has -07:00) since I'm in a different time zone.

```
<date>2015-12-09T15:34:02.0177724-07:00</date>
```